# Directory of professional vertical web services

Tags: data-request

I have a made full business solution for small businesses on construction sites and want to publish it in a directory to better find it. I don't want to rely on SEO only.

There are either **horizontal services** every business needs, as webmail, online spreadsheets, hosting services

OR

**vertical services** for specific businesses, e.g. a tennis court rental solution, a barber shop online solution, a pizza delivery service solution or whatever a business is targetet to.

Having googled for a long time, i just **can** find directories for horizontal services but not for professional vertical services, with

- online registration for the business owner
- billing on a monthly basis
- ready to use customer frontend
- hotline services and so on.

such a service replaces the need of lots of software to be installed on a pc/notebook/server and can be set up within minutes.

already tried yahoo, google, dmoz, ... for weeks but there is no way to filter and find such vertical services.

EDIT: Is there a protocol to publish such services? In the webservice definition once there was UDDI specified but I don't this of great relevance today.

Comment: The only way that I could see to get this 'question' within the scope of this site would be to either ask if there are standards for distributing this sort of information, or if there are existing repositories of this info.  I doubt the second one would be useful, as many of the services would have a limited coverage area.

Comment: @Joe: Thanks, good point! Added the protocol question in the EDIT section.